# Python cannot find a directory

Tags: python, directory

I wrote a code like this with jupyter notebook in a project;

```
import os


image_path = r'C:\Users\ays\Desktop\IR\01.jpg'
image_files = os.listdir(image_path)
img = cv2.imread(os.path.join(image_path,image_files))
cv2.imshow('image',img)
```

it gives an error like;

> [WinError 3] The system cannot find the path specified: 'C:\Users\ays\Desktop\IR\01.jpg'

i was trying to print an image and
i had a directory problem

Comment: `image_path` isn't a directory, it's the path of a specific image file. It ends with `01.jpg`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The argument to `os.listdir()` must be the directory, not the image file, so remove `\01.jpg`.

Then you'll need to loop over the result of `os.listdir()`, since it returns a list.

```
import os

image_path = r'C:\Users\ays\Desktop\IR'
image_files = os.listdir(image_path)
for file in image_files:
    img = cv2.imread(os.path.join(image_path,file))
    cv2.imshow('image',img)
```

Comment: but I want to work on an image in file. Do you know how I should write?

Comment: Then just use `img = cv2.imread(image_path)`, you don't need anything else.

Comment: I will do as you say, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Your `image_path` seems to be a file, not a directory. Drop the file name and you should be OK:

```py
image_path = r'C:\Users\ays\Desktop\IR'
```

Comment: but I want to work on an image in file. Do you know how I should write?